# How to return 'faiss' unique vector id on 'add_with_ids' trained index?

Tags: python, knn

I'm using Facebook's faiss index with custom indexes using the `add_with_ids` method. In inference time I use `distance, ID = model.search()` which returns the custom ID it was trained with. Is it possible to return also a unique id without retraining? Or just return the actual closest vector?

Thank you!

Comment: At least the [Flat Index](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Faiss-indexes#flat-indexes) supports the operation you are looking for
`they do support efficient direct vector access (with reconstruct and reconstruct_n)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you provided the actual vectors, you presumably know how to map ids to vectors. 
Most Faiss indexes in do not store the vectors, because they need to be compressed to fit in RAM.

Comment: In my case, many vectors could belong to the same cluster (ID) so I cannot reverse map them.

Comment: You can add_with_ids with the vector ids instead of the cluster ids.